# bs4 find возвращает None

Tags: python, html, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

[image: Выделил строчку]

Я хочу записать в переменную выделенный div:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
root = soup.find('div', class_='sc-1mqhavm-0 gtbDEj')
```

Однако, после вывода переменой root обнаруживаю объект None, что означает, что find просто не обнаружил div с классом sc-1mqhavm-0 gtbDEj

Comment: А он точно есть в возвращаемом `HTML`? Возможно, что он подгружается с помощью `JavaScript`. Выполните `soup.prettify()` и попробуйте найти нужный `div` в выводе.

Comment: Попробовал, в итоге разобрался и спарсил то, что надо.
Однако на втором сайте при аналогичной ситуации обнаружил, что при вводе soup.prettify() python возвращает html, в котором просто нет контейнера, в котором находилось огромное количество информации. Как в таком случае действовать?

Comment: В таком случае Вы можете имитировать браузер с помощью `Selenium`, чтобы исполнить `JavaScript` и загрузить нужные данные.